# DateTime field read only

Tags: .net, datetime

Why .Net DateTime properties cannot be assigned to? It would be useful to be able to do things like:

```
DateTime saveNow = DateTime.Now;
saveNow.Second = 0; //Error, it does not compile
```

Comment: Mutable value types are evil.

Comment: If I understand correctly you're saying that:

DateTime is a struct (not a class) and mutable struct are bad practice. That's why they are, by design, not mutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I summarize what @SLaks and @Gabe said:

DateTime is a struct (not a class) and mutable struct are bad practice. Check here for details  [Why are mutable structs evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil)

Because of this, DateTime is by design not mutable.

To set the DateTime 'seconds' field to 0 you can use this code:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime saveNow 
 = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because they are accessor properties, thus read only.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime saveNow 
   = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute, 0);
```

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to know why DateTime has only Get accessor and not Set accessor. @SLaks answered shortly to it.

Thank you for the code, it's the way I solved my problem. And now I more sure it is the correct way to go.

Comment: @user511956 - Please mark it as the answer then, since it solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
DateTime saveNow = DateTime.Now;
```

<del>`saveNow.AddSeconds(-savenow.Second);`</del>
   `AddSeconds` doesn't change the value, it returns a new instance with the new value. This version works:

```
saveNow = saveNow.AddSeconds(-savenow.Second);
```

Comment: **No**.  This will have no effect.  `DateTime` is _immutable_.